# Hunger not decreasing in Minecraft Ultra Hardcore difficulty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been playing on Ultra Hardcore in Minecraft update 1.12.2 (PC version), but my hunger isn't decreasing at all (the hunger bar goes almost never down while sprinting). Are there any commands that makes the hunger go down quicker?

I want more challenge in Ultra Hardcore, since it is quite easy now.

Comment: To my knowledge, this hasn't been added yet. The /effect command can help. Use it like /effect @p <Effect> <Time> <Level> (replacing each for the appropriate value) For <effect> replace it with "hunger" to decrease health.

Comment: What did you use for UHC mode? Just `gamerule naturalRegeneration false`? Or a complex system made by someone else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`/effect`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/effect) command ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/effect&oldid=1241588)) to give yourself hunger. But that's probably not what you want. You probably just started the game and still have saturation points from the start, which is a time when you don't lose hunger points. So just wait a bit and keep playing and it will start to behave "normally" after a bit.